# How can i rotate an UIImageView without deforming the image?

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to make a spinning wheel that slowly stops

```
-(void) applyPhysics {

if (rotatingSpeed < -1) {
    rotatingSpeed++;
}
else if (rotatingSpeed > 1 )
{
    rotatingSpeed--;
}
else
{
    rotatingSpeed = 0;
}
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(imageView.transform, rotatingSpeed / 57.3);}
```

making /57.3 is like angle / 180 * PI

But the wheel keeps deforming in a strange way.. how can I rotate it WITHOUT deforming it? the wheel is totally symmetric in almost any way...
Thanks!

Comment: Can you show an example of the deformation?

Comment: You seem to be using a timed function rather than the built in animation, is there a particular reason for that?

Comment: -Joshua : here are screenshots of how it starts and how it ends. [IMG]http://i43.tinypic.com/vmukgj.png[/IMG] and [IMG]http://i42.tinypic.com/9qelnn.png[/IMG] 
-felix: how could i use the build in animation? yes, I use         `[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 
                                         target:self 
                                       selector:@selector(applyPhysics) 
                                       userInfo:nil 
                                        repeats:YES];
`

Comment: check out the Size Inspector in your xib. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It occurs because you make transformation over transformation.

Try put object in original position(0 degree) before each transform.

Good luck!

Comment: It was an initialization problem after all. The image was not correctly drawn the first time, and so, after rotating it, it became strange. Thank all of you for the answers!